# Is there a way to separate "addtocart" and "buynow" from the same form?

Tags: python, django

I'm making a e-commerce website, right now I have a buy now button, when pressed will add item to cart and redirect to "cart" page, I want to have a "addtocart" botton which will add the product to card but won't redirect under the same function. Please help me

carts/modes.py

```
def buy_now(request, slug):
    request.session.set_expiry(120000)

    try:
        the_id = request.session['cart_id'] 
    except:
        new_cart = Cart()
        new_cart.save()
        request.session['cart_id'] = new_cart.id
        the_id = new_cart.id

    cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)
    try :
        product = Product_info.objects.get(slug=slug)
    except Product_info.DoesNotExist:
        pass

    product_var = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
        qty = request.POST['qty']
        for item in request.POST:
            key = item
            val = request.POST[key]
            print(key,val)
            try:
                v = Variation.objects.get(product = product,cat__iexact=key,title__iexact=val)
                product_var.append(v)
            except:
                pass
        cart_item = CartItem.objects.create(cart = cart,product = product)
        if len(product_var) > 0:
            cart_item.variations.add(*product_var)
        cart_item.quantity = qty
        cart_item.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("cart"))

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("cart"))
```

template.html

```
<form class="form pull-right" method='POST' action="{% url 'buy_now' product.slug %}"> {% csrf_token %}


        {% if product.variation_set.all %}

            {% if product.variation_set.models %}
            <select class = "form-control" name='model'>
                {% for item in product.variation_set.models %}
                    <option value ="{{ item.title }}">{{ item.title }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
            {% endif %}

            {% if product.variation_set.sizes %}
            <select class = "form-control" name='size'>
                {% for item in product.variation_set.sizes %}
                    <option value ="{{ item.title }}">{{ item.title }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
            {% endif %}

            {% if product.variation_set.colors %}
            <select class = "form-control" name='color'>
                {% for item in product.variation_set.colors %}
                    <option value ="{{ item.title }}">{{ item.title }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
            {% endif %}

        {% endif %}

    <input class = 'form-control' name="qty" type="number"/ value="1"/>
    <input class = 'btn btn-danger'type="submit" value="Buynow"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Please post a specific question

Comment: Totally unrelated but this `except: pass` is the very worse thing you could do. Always only catch only the specific exception you expect and can handle (here `Variation.DoesNotExist`) and let other exceptions propagate.

Answer (score 2):

you can use it within same view and separate the button with `name` attribute instead.

```
<input class = 'btn btn-danger' type="submit" name="buynow" value="Buynow"/>
<input class = 'btn btn-danger' type="submit" name="addtocart" value="Add to Cart"/>
```

then in your views:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
   if 'buynow' in request.POST:
      ....
      return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("cart"))
   elif 'addtocart' in request.POST:
      # code to response add to cart button
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is partial, but from that I think you need to redirect and do the  `POST`actions (both **add to cart** and **buy now**) .

Your buttons in the template

```
 <input class = 'btn btn-danger'type="submit" value="Buynow"/>
```

Update

```
<input class = 'btn btn-primary' type="button" value="Add to Cart" id="id_AddtoCart/>
<input class = 'btn btn-danger' type="submit" value="Buynow"/>
```

And write `AJAX POST`method for **add to cart** functionality

```
$("#id_AddtoCart").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "/cart/ajax/addtocart/", #example URL, replace with your ajax
  data : $('#cartform').serialize(),


  success: function(result){
    // template update code from the result
    }
})  
});
```

the view should be like below for add to cart
Change Form,Model and fileds to actual values

```
def add_to_cart(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CartItemForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cart = CartItem.add(product=form.cleaned_data['product'], quantity=form.cleaned_data['quantity'])
        data = {"status": "success", "total": cart.qty, "count": cart.count }
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json")
return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"status": "error"}), content_type="application/json")
```

Then you can use the **buynow** view for the form submission from the "Buy Now" button

Always better to use AJAX functionality for the features like **Add to Cart**

```
def buy_now(request, slug):
request.session.set_expiry(120000)

try:
    the_id = request.session['cart_id'] 
except:
    new_cart = Cart()
    new_cart.save()
    request.session['cart_id'] = new_cart.id
    the_id = new_cart.id

cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)
try :
    product = Product_info.objects.get(slug=slug)
except Product_info.DoesNotExist:
    pass

product_var = []
if request.method == 'POST':
    qty = request.POST['qty']
    for item in request.POST:
        key = item
        val = request.POST[key]
        print(key,val)
        try:
            v = Variation.objects.get(product = product,cat__iexact=key,title__iexact=val)
            product_var.append(v)
        except:
            pass
    cart_item = CartItem.objects.create(cart = cart,product = product)
    if len(product_var) > 0:
        cart_item.variations.add(*product_var)
    cart_item.quantity = qty
    cart_item.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("cart"))
```